# Embed if condition inside javascript function with HTML output

Tags: javascript, php, survey

I am trying to update a script written by someone else and need some help, as I do not work in Javascript often. The script is part of a SurveyGizmo survey, so may use some syntax/functions not standard in Javascript.

The script below works. It takes the results of each category's quiz score and prints a message stored in another variable in the survey. There are 5 categories. The output looks like this:

> Category 1 Score
>
> Category 1 Message
>
> Category 2 Score
>
> Category 2 Message

etc..

Below this code is my question.

```
function sgapiQuizResults(){
  %%html .= '<div class="recommendations"><div class="something">Recommendations</div>'; 
  foreach (sgapiQuizMessages() as %%category => %%message) {
    %%html .= '<div class="recommendation '. sgapiCSSClassName(%%category) .'">';
      %%html .= '<div class="header">' . %%category .'</div>';
      %%html .= '<div class="graphic">'. sgapiScore(%%category) . '</div>';
      %%html .= '<div class="content">' . %%message . '</div>';
    %%html .= '</div>';
  }
  %%html .= '</div>';
  return %%html;
}
```

What I would like to do is modify this to add additional messaging that cannot be stored in a variable. Basically, I would like to add a condition similar to as follows:

```
if ( Number(sgapiGetValue(8)) < 3 ) {
      %%html .= "Message for Question 8";
}
if ( Number(sgapiGetValue(9)) < 3 ) {
      %%html .= "Lorem Ipsum for 9";
}
if ( Number(sgapiGetValue(10)) < 3 ) {
      %%html .= "Dolor for 10";
}
... and so on ...
```

The output of which would look like:

> Category 1 Score
>
> Category 1 Message
>
> Message for Question 8
>
> Category 2 Score
>
> Category 2 Message
>
> Lorem Ipsum for 9

etc..

I have been successful at simply adding `&&html .= 'Hello World';` to the code, having that message printed to each category; however, any time I try to include a conditional statement, the script breaks.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
function sgapiQuizResults(){
  %%html .= '<div class="recommendations"><div class="something">Recommendations</div>'; 
  foreach (sgapiQuizMessages() as %%category => %%message) {
      %%html .= '<div class="recommendation '. sgapiCSSClassName(%%category) .'">';
      %%html .= '<div class="header">' . %%category .'</div>';
      %%html .= '<div class="graphic">'. sgapiScore(%%category) . '</div>';
      %%html .= '<div class="content">' . %%message . '</div>';
      if ( Number(sgapiGetValue(8)) < 3 ) {
          %%html .= '<div class="content">Message for Question 8</div>';
      }
      if ( Number(sgapiGetValue(9)) < 3 ) {
          %%html .= '<div class="content">Lorem Ipsum for 9</div>';
      }
      if ( Number(sgapiGetValue(10)) < 3 ) {
          %%html .= '<div class="content">Dolor for 10</div>';
      }
      %%html .= '</div>';
  }
  %%html .= '</div>';
  return %%html;
}
```

revised.
can try this?

Comment: I want to include specific responses, not the n. Each response is based on whether there was a certain score, thus `if ( Number(sgapiGetValue(8)) < 3 )`. I'll edit my question to clarify.

Comment: @AnthonySchmidt i noticed the cause might be because of your ' or " usage.